# Integral of something like Gamma Function

Tags: calculus, integration, gamma-function

I am currently reading a paper that uses this integral as being less that one automatically. I am just wondering how do I know this to be true? Any help would be appreciated. Kindest regards, Catherine

\begin{equation}
 \int^{\varepsilon^{-2}cT}_0 e^{-\eta} \eta^{-\beta/m} \, d\eta
\end{equation}

Everything apart from $\eta$ is constant.

Comment: It depends on the values of the constants, e.g. if you use $\beta = m$ the integral does not even converge

Comment: so $\epsilon$ is a small positive parameter, $\beta$ is positive and bigger than $m$ such that $\beta/m \geq 1$. $c$ is also positive. Apart from that I have no information on what the parameters are.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [incomplete Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function). Indeed, your integral can be expressed in terms of the lower incomplete gamma function $\gamma(s, x)$:
$$\int_0^{\epsilon^{-2}cT} e^{-\eta}\eta^{-\beta/m}\,d\eta=\gamma\left(-\beta/m+1,\epsilon^{-2}cT\right)$$
Right now, I don't think there is a way to show that this integral will be less than one, unless contraints are placed on the parameters.

Comment: Hello, I have gone through some of the constants in a comment. T is also positive. The other constants are not specified in the paper

Comment: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/17442508.2011.624628 This is the paper :)

Comment: Could you tell me on what page they use this assumption? Thanks! Also, if $\beta/m \ge 1$, then your function is not integrable around 0, so it diverges.

Comment: So it is used at the bottom of page eight. :)